# Why are my variables, set by linecache, printing on multiple lines?

Tags: python

```
import linecache
from random import randint

number = randint(1,2500)
firstnamenumber = randint(1,1219)
print "Male(m) or Female(f)"
choice = raw_input()

last = linecache.getline('lastname.txt',number)
malefirst = linecache.getline ('malename.txt',firstnamenumber)
femalefirst = linecache.getline ('femalename.txt',firstnamenumber)


print"{}{}".format(malefirst,last)
```

My idea here is to set the last, malefirst, femalefirst variables to random lines within each .txt files. Then I want to print a first name and last name on the same line. However, this is printing two separate lines instead. Where is my mistake? Could it be in the .txt file itself? If so, I am unsure what would trigger it.

the .txt files are files containing names from a census report.

Comment: Yes it is likely getting the new line character at the end of the line of the .txt file and printing that. Try changing the last line to `print"{}{}".format(malefirst.rstrip('\n'),last.rstrip('\n'))`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this and update